# javascript/jquery function scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

```
 function onMouseClickFunction() {

    $mapCanvas.click(function (e) {
        var x = cursor.getCursorPositionInCanvasX(e.pageX),
            y = cursor.getCursorPositionInCanvasY(e.pageY);
```

what is the variable scope in this example is it function onMouseclickFunction or perhaps the anonymous function of jquery?

What i ment is that javascript uses hoisting creating variables at the top of its parent function, so where is hoisting done in this example?

Comment: If hoisting is what you're after, check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085839/surprised-that-global-variable-has-undefined-value-in-javascript/9085872#9085872

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean the variables `x` and `y`, then it is the anonymous function passed to `click()`.

`var` always scopes to the *current* function.

> What i ment is that javascript uses hoisting creating variables at the top of its parent function, so where is hoisting done in this example?

Hoisting means that when you use `var`, the variable will be scoped for the function, even if you have previously tried to use it.

i.e.

```
function () {
    var x = 1;

    function () {
         alert(x);
         var x = 2;
    }
}
```

If the inner function was called, it would alert `undefined` because `var x = 2` creates a new `x` in the scope of the inner function (`var` is hoisted), but the assignment doesn't take place until after the alert (since the assignment is not hoisted).

All the `var` statements in the question appear at the top of the function they appear in, so hoisting makes no difference.

Answer (score 5):

Every variable properly declared will always have a local scope to the current function.

Since you're using the `var` statement properly, your `x` and `y` variables are local to your anonymous function.

---

If you want to be able to access those variables from your `onMouseClickFunction` function, you should declare them outside your `click` event handler. You'll still have access to them from within the click handler, since that function itself is declared within the `onMouseClickFunction` function.

This is known as JavaScript's scope chain lookup: if a variable you're using has not been declared within the local scope, JavaScript will look for it in the scope just above the current one (which in the case of your anonymous function is the outer `onMouseClickFunction`). If it's not declared there either, it'll keep on looking all the way up the scope, till it reaches the global scope.

If the variable is not found anywhere through the scope chain, it'll be declared as a new variables *in the global scope*. That's why it's imperative to *always* declare your variables with a `var` statement, as you've done.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the latter (the anonymous function), since that's the function in which the variables are being declared.

Answer (score 0):

What you have created here is a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures).

As such, the anonymous function would inherit the scope of onMouseClickFunction, but the variables x and y are only in the scope of the anonymous function.