# issue with variable declaration in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    name = "Tim";
    function greet() {
      console.log(name);
      var name = "David" ;
    }
    greet();
</script>
```

Why does the result show "undefined"?  I expected Tim or David.

Comment: Here is the extensive explanation  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9085872/2413470][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9085872/2413470

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 'name' you declare is a global variable.
Inside the function, you declare it again, so you lose the visibility of the global one. But you use the variable before it is defined.

```
name = "Tim";  // global name here
function greet() {
  // var name; // here name is automatically declared ( because of hoisting ) but undefined
  console.log(name);    // here you use name before it is defined
  var name = "David" ;  // here name is defined
}
greet();
```

Javascript has scope in functions, that's important.
Google for 'javascript hoisting' it will help.

Comment: +1 Exactly. Javascript sees the re-declaration of the variable in the new scope, so it cancels out the original, but then it's used before it's set.

Answer (score 1):

Chage it like this,

```
var name = "Tim";
function greet() {
  console.log(name);
  name = "David" ;
}
greet();
```