# How to pre-calculate stuff for use in a waitForKeyElements() callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am using this amazing script, [waitForKeyElements()](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) (wfke), which helps dealing with dynamically loaded content in userscripts.

It does a perfect job, but I am having a lot of trouble pre-calculating some variables, and then using that when wfke executes.

Basically, It is correctly running hundreds of times for a list of nodes, that all get loaded right away (after the page is loaded). But I cannot be creating expensive variables and doing expensive calculations for every single item in this list. So I try to do these outside of the wfke function.

As you can see in the following example, I have tried two different ways to pre-set the variable "icons", both do not work. I am guessing this is probably a feature of `@require` scripts? Would copy-pasting the script into my main script fix the issue? Would that be the only way?

```
// @require         https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
var icons = $('some stuff');
//Run for every BOX element that gets loaded by ajax
waitForKeyElements(".box", main);

function main(jqnode){
  if (typeof icons === 'undefined') { //icons is undefined here, and will be again the next time this function is run.
  var icons = $('some stuff');
  }
 jqnode.append(icons);
}
```

In Chrome, Tampermonkey (beta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) and to "[Surprised that global variable has undefined value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085839/surprised-that-global-variable-has-undefined-value-in-javascript/9085872#9085872)".

When you do this:

```
var icons = $('some stuff');
```

**anywhere** within the function `main()` scope, it creates a local variable that is used in place of the global-scope variable.  This function-scope variable is undefined at the time of the `if()` statement.

Also, the question is not clear; I assume you want to ***copy*** the icons to all `.box` nodes?   The code is currently structured to have only one set of icons and to move them to whatever `.box` appears last.

If you want a copy, use [jQuery's `.clone()` method](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=clone).  Something like:

```
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js

var icons = $('some stuff');

//Run for every BOX element that gets loaded by ajax
waitForKeyElements (".box", main);

function main (jqnode){
    jqnode.append (icons.clone () );
    /*-- Or use this to copy event handlers, but should be using 
        `.on()` instead, anyway.

    jqnode.append (icons.clone (true) );
    */
}
```

If that is not what you want, clarify and specify.