# Using 'var' and 'this' in the global scope in node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been told that the 'this' in the global scope means the global object, and using 'var' in the global scope will define properties in the global object. However, I have no idea why I get the following behaviors when using 'var' and 'this' in the node.js program. I find a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085839/surprised-that-global-variable-has-undefined-value-in-javascript) about this, but I don't think my question is related to the hoisting. Could someone explain it? Thanks. (I'm using node.js version 0.12.4)

```
yyy = 20;
global.zzz = 30;

var xxx = 10;
this.nnn = 40;

var v = function() {
    //console.log(global);  // <-- There is 'yyy' in the global object as expected
    console.log(this.yyy);  // <-- 20 as expected
    console.log(yyy);       // <-- 20 as expected

    //console.log(global);  // <-- There is 'zzz' in the global object as expected
    console.log(this.zzz);  // <-- 30 as expected
    console.log(zzz);       // <-- 30 as expected

    //console.log(global);  // <-- There is no 'xxx' in the global object.   WHY??? where is 'xxx' located?
    console.log(this.xxx);  // <-- undefined as expected, because there is not 'xxx' in the global object.
    console.log(xxx);       // <-- 10.   WHY??? where is 'xxx' located?

    //console.log(global);  // <-- There is no 'nnn' in the global object.  WHY??? where is 'nnn' located?
    console.log(this.nnn);  // <-- undefined as expected, because there is not 'nnn' in the global object.
    console.log(nnn);       // <-- ReferenceError: nnn is not defined.   WHY ReferenceError instead of 'undefined'???
}

v();
```

I wrap the above code to an HTML file, like below, and test in the Chrome (version 44.0.2403.157 m). The results are all as expected. Are there any important concepts I'm missing in Node.js?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
         yyy = 20;
         window.zzz = 30;            // change global.zzz to window.zzz

         var xxx = 10;
         this.nnn = 40;

         var v = function() {
             console.log(this.yyy);  // <-- 20 as expected
             console.log(yyy);       // <-- 20 as expected

             console.log(this.zzz);  // <-- 30 as expected
             console.log(zzz);       // <-- 30 as expected

             console.log(this.xxx);  // <-- 10 as expected
             console.log(xxx);       // <-- 10 as expected

             console.log(this.nnn);  // <-- 40 as expected
             console.log(nnn);       // <-- 40 as expected
         }

         v();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## ============= Update ==============

After digging into the node.js source code, I think I've understood the reason why the sample code would produce such outputs. Briefly speaking, when launch xxx.js by node.js with "node.js xxx.js", the xxx.js would be loaded by node.js in a "module loading" way.

1) In src/node.js in the node.js source codes:

If launching javascript file with the form of "node xxx.js", node will execute the js file by using Module.runMain();

```
} else if (process.argv[1]) {
      ...
      } else {
        // Main entry point into most programs:
        Module.runMain();
      }
```

2) in lib/module.js:

The call flow in this file are: "Module.runMain()" ==> "Module._load()" ==> "Module.load()" ==> "Module._compile()" ==> "compiledWrapper.apply(self.exports, ...)"

```
// bootstrap main module.
Module.runMain = function() {
  // Load the main module--the command line argument.
  Module._load(process.argv[1], null, true);
  ...
};

Module._load = function(request, parent, isMain) {
  ...
  try {
    module.load(filename);
    ...
  } finally {
  ...
}

Module.prototype.load = function(filename) {
  ...
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
  ...
}

Module._extensions['.js'] = function(module, filename) {
  ...
  module._compile(stripBOM(content), filename);
};

NativeModule.wrapper = [
  '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ',
  '\n});'
];

Module.prototype._compile = function(content, filename) {
  var self = this;
  ...
  // create wrapper function
  var wrapper = Module.wrap(content); // wrap in the above 
                                      // "NativeModule.wrapper"

  var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, { filename: filename });
  ...
  var args = [self.exports, require, self, filename, dirname];
  return compiledWrapper.apply(self.exports, args);
}
```

Because "_compile()" function is in the prototype structure of the Module object, the "self" (or "this") variable in "_compile()" must be the Module itself. Therefore, the whole javascript file loading process of "node xxx.js" is just like to execute a function in which the content of the function is xxx.js, and the "this" in that function would be the "Module.exports" (because Module.exports is the first argument passed into the "apply()" function at the end of _compile())

Hence, the whole loading process is equivalent to the following javascript codes:

```
function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  /* the content of xxx.js, and "this" would refer to "module.exports" */
}
```

After knowing this, then the original example codes could be understood with the following 2 simple and basic javascript rules:

1. The "this" object in a function would be the "global object" if the function is called in "xxx();" form rather than "y.xxx();" form.
2. Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object).

Hence, the detailed explanations of the example codes line by line are as follows:

```
yyy = 20; // Assign a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates
          // it as a property of the global object, hence, "yyy" would be 
          // located in the global object.

global.zzz = 30; // explicitly add a property named "zzz" in the global 
                 // object.

var xxx = 10; // "xxx" will be a local variable in the module, and is not  
              // assigned to the "module.exports". Hence, it actually acts as 
              // a local variable in the function implicitly created by 
              // node.js to load the file as a module. Due to lexical 
              // scoping rule, it can only be accessed from the function 
              // defined in this file (module).

this.nnn = 40; // This file is loaded as a module by "applying" a function
               // and pass module.exports as the first argument of apply(), 
               // hence, the "this" here would refer to "module.exports".

console.log("this === module.exports? " + (this === module.exports)); // true

console.log(module); // you can see a "exports: { nnn: 40 }" lines in the 
                     // module object

var v = function() {
    // according to the call site syntax (v();), the "this" object here would 
    // be the global object.
    console.log("this === global? " + (this === global)); // true

    console.log(this.yyy);  // <-- 20 as expected (global objects has "yyy", 
                            // and "this" refers to the global object. 
                            // Bingo~!)

    console.log(yyy);       // <-- 20 as expected (according to lexical 
                            // scoping rule, it could find "yyy" in the 
                            // global VariableObject (equals to global 
                            // object). Bingo~!)

    console.log(this.zzz);  // <-- 30 as expected (global object has "zzz", 
                            // and "this" refers to the global object. 
                            // Bingo~!)

    console.log(zzz);       // <-- 30 as expected (according to lexical 
                            // scoping rule, it could find "zzz" in the 
                            // global VariableObject (equals to global 
                            // object). Bingo~!)

    console.log(this.xxx);  // <-- undefined as expected ("xxx" is not 
                            // defined in the global object, "xxx" is just a 
                            // local variable in the function implicitly 
                            // created by node.js to load this file, and 
                            // "this" here refers to the module.exports. 
                            // Hence, "undefined")

    console.log(xxx);       // <-- 10 as expected (according to lexical 
                            // scoping rule, it could find "xxx" in the outer 
                            // environment context of this function. Bingo~!)

    console.log(this.nnn);  // <-- undefined as expected ("nnn" is actually 
                            // defined as a property of "module.exports", and 
                            // "this" here refers to the global object, 
                            // hence, "undefined")

    console.log(nnn);       // <-- ReferenceError: nnn is not defined. 
                            // (according to the lexical scoping rule, it 
                            // could not find any "variable name" equals to 
                            // "nnn" in the scope chain. Because nnn is just 
                            // the property of the module.exports, it could 
                            // not be found in the lexical scoping searching. 
                            // hence, "ReferenceError")
}

v();
```

Comment: `var` declare a locale variable, if you do not use `var` it create a global variable

Comment: @Hacketo: That's not really the question though.

Comment: `xxx` → available through simple closure scoping; `nnn` → well, there is no bare `var nnn` defined anywhere in scope.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha well what is the point ? "There is no 'xxx' in the global object.   WHY??? WHY??? where is 'xxx' located?"

Comment: `xxx` is a local variable in your example, because you are not executing in the global context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit misguided, since in global context, all four pairs return the same result, both in Node and (replacing `window` for `global`) in a browser. This is because `var` has no meaning in global scope, and defines properties on `this`; since `this` is the global object, `this.nnn`, `global.zzz` and `yyy` all also define properties on `global`. When reading, `nnn`, `zzz` and `yyy` are not recognised as local variables, thus they are looked up on global object (`window` here instead of `global` so it would run in Stack Overflow instead of Node, but same principle will apply):

```js
yyy = 20;
window.zzz = 30;

var xxx = 10;
this.nnn = 40;

var v = function() {
    snippet.log(Object.keys(window));

    snippet.log("this.yyy: " + this.yyy);
    snippet.log("yyy: " + yyy);

    snippet.log("this.zzz: " + this.zzz);
    snippet.log("zzz: " + zzz);

    snippet.log("this.xxx: " + this.xxx);
    snippet.log("xxx: " + xxx);

    snippet.log("this.nnn: " + this.nnn);
    snippet.log("nnn: " + nnn);
};

v();
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

However, enclose that in some non-global scope, and things change for `xxx` - notice how it is no longer defined on the global object:

```js
function vv() {

  yyy = 20;          // = this.yyy a.k.a. window.yyy
  window.zzz = 30;

  var xxx = 10;      // local variable xxx
  this.nnn = 40;     // = window.nnn

  var v = function() {
      snippet.log(Object.keys(window));

      snippet.log("this.yyy: " + this.yyy);
      snippet.log("yyy: " + yyy);

      snippet.log("this.zzz: " + this.zzz);
      snippet.log("zzz: " + zzz);

      snippet.log("this.xxx: " + this.xxx);
      snippet.log("xxx: " + xxx);

      snippet.log("this.nnn: " + this.nnn);
      snippet.log("nnn: " + nnn);
  };

  v();
  
}

vv();
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Everything stays the same except for the `this.xxx`/`xxx` part. `this.xxx` should be `undefined`, since `xxx` is a local variable, and not defined on the global object like the other three. However, as a local variable, it is getting captured by any functions created in that scope: we say that "`v` closes over `xxx`", or "`v` is a closure over `xxx`", so the local variable `xxx` can be seen from `v`.

In fact, even cooler, closure means that all local variables that are visible at the scope where `v` is created are visible by `v` as well, *wherever we call `v` from* - illustrated in the following snippet:

```js
var v;

function vv() {

  yyy = 20;          // = this.yyy a.k.a. window.yyy
  window.zzz = 30;

  var xxx = 10;      // local variable xxx
  this.nnn = 40;     // = window.nnn

  v = function() {
      snippet.log(Object.keys(window));

      snippet.log("this.yyy: " + this.yyy);
      snippet.log("yyy: " + yyy);

      snippet.log("this.zzz: " + this.zzz);
      snippet.log("zzz: " + zzz);

      snippet.log("this.xxx: " + this.xxx);
      snippet.log("xxx: " + xxx);

      snippet.log("this.nnn: " + this.nnn);
      snippet.log("nnn: " + nnn);
  };

}

vv();

// snippet.log("xxx before calling v: " + xxx); // ReferenceError
v();
// snippet.log("xxx after calling v: " + xxx); // ReferenceError
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note that here we can still read `xxx` as `10` inside `v`, even though the place where we are *calling* the function *v* has no idea about `xxx`.

Note that the only way to get the global scope in Node is to execute your program interactively (`node < stuff.js`); if you execute it as a file (`node stuff.js`), a file will execute in its own scope, and you will not see this effect:

```
// a.js
var xxx = 10;
console.log(this.xxx);

$ node < a.js
10

$ node a.js
undefined
```

Comment: Thanks~. For this statement: "This is because var has no meaning in global scope.", why there is another statement in [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) mentioned that I can use 'var' in the global scope?

Comment: You can use it, but the result will be the same as if you didn't use it.

Comment: Thanks again~ If using 'var' in the global scope is the same as if I didn't use it, why the results of 'var xxx = 10' and 'xxx = 10' are different in the node.js file execution mode? and why 'console.log(xxx)' could result in 10 in the node.js file execution mode? and why using 'this.nnn' in global scope in the node.js file execution mode could not define properties in some 'object' in the file's own scoped object?

Comment: @WeiHu Read to the end of the answer :) You did not have a global scope in the first place.

Comment: Thanks~ The end of your answer really inspires me. And after digging into the node.js source codes, I think I could fully understand your "the end of your answer" :) I'll update what I have learned in the original post.

Comment: @Amadan - Using `var` at global scope isn't the same as not using it. The property created by `var` on the global object cannot be deleted. A property created by assigning to an undeclared identifier (what I call [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)) or by assigning to a property on `this` can be deleted.