# Global variable unavailable within function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I'm working on reproducing a live filter box with handsontable based on the built in search functionality at http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta6/demo-search-for-values.html.

Right Now I'm working with the simplest use case (http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/uL3L4teL/) from the docs.

As explained in the docs, In this code if you enter a search string, you get the matching cells outputted to the console using the following function:

```
         Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(searchFiled, 'keyup', function (event) {
                var queryResult = hot.search.query(this.value);

                console.log(queryResult);
                hot.render();
```

I want to grab the rows in the data array that match the search string and filter the original data 'data' by the search string before redisplaying the table. This partially works using:

```
 Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(searchFiled, 'keyup', function (event) {
    var queryResult = hot.search.query(this.value);

    console.log(queryResult);
    rows = getRowsFromObjects(queryResult);
    console.log('hot', hot.getData());
    console.log('data', data);
    var data = hot.getData();
    var filtered = data.filter(function(d, ix) { return rows.indexOf(ix) >= 0; });
    console.log('filtered', filtered);

    hot.loadData(filtered);


});
```

As you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/uL3L4teL/2/ , but I need to replace

```
var data = hot.getData();
```

(a handsontable function which gets the current data in the table) with the global 'data' (defined at the top) for the searching to work. But the global data is undefined in the function. How can I fix this?

Comment: `var data;` is hoisted to the top and the variable will be undefined, until the `data = hot.getData()` line is reached. Use a different variable name, or `window.data` if it's a global variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Surprised that global variable has undefined value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085839/surprised-that-global-variable-has-undefined-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "global" data variable that you are referring to "at the top" is this one

```
var
data = [
  ['Nissan', 2012, 'black', 'black'],
  ['Nissan', 2013, 'blue', 'blue'],
  ['Chrysler', 2014, 'yellow', 'black'],
  ['Volvo', 2015, 'yellow', 'gray']
]
```

then that is not global.  That variable is local to the DOMContentLoaded event handler function. I presume even though you declare the other event handlers within that same block, they are being called with a different scope, making that variable unavailable.  As was suggested in a comment, you can assign it to a global variable like window, or just declare it in a global scope.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: This is not true. It *is* in the same scope, but as Niet explains in the comments, there's another variable with the same name that shadows the "global" variable.

Comment: Juhana is correct, var data = hot.getData(); is shadowing the data variable that I mentioned in my answer.