# Why a local scope doesn't refer on a global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global, local

I have a problem with a local scope. The second console.log doesn't show "a" value, but shows undefined. Why so?

```
"use strict"

console.log(a); //undefined 
var a = "a";
function b(){
  console.log(a); // why is undefined here? 
  var a = "a1";
  console.log(a); // here is "a1"
}
b();
```

Comment: Remove the second `var` to _assign_ a value to the global `var a` instead of _redeclare_ it.

Comment: var a inside a function is also a global scope..why you declare both..

Comment: if your brother and friend are both named "bob", you need to be more specific on a car ride with both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Surprised that global variable has undefined value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085839/surprised-that-global-variable-has-undefined-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

JS will process your code like:

```
"use strict"

var a; // undefined 
console.log(a); //undefined 

a = "a";

function b(){
  var a; // undefined

  console.log(a); // all is clear, LOCAL variable a is undefined. 

  a = "a1";
  console.log(a); // here is "a1"
}

b();
```

read more about hoisting [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Also you can read about [Function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting), this is an important part of JavaScript fundamentals too.

Answer (score 1):

> **Object-Oriented JavaScript, 2nd Edition:** When your JavaScript program execution enters a new function, all the variables declared
>   anywhere in the function are moved (or elevated, or hoisted) to the
>   top of the function. This is an important concept to keep in mind.
>   Further, only the declaration is hoisted, meaning only the presence of
>   the variable is moved to the top. Any assignments stay where they are.
>   In the preceding example, the declaration of the local variable a was
>   hoisted to the top.

```
var a = 123;

function f() {

    var a; // same as: var a = undefined;

    alert(a); // undefined

    a = 1;

    alert(a); // 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoisting is JavaScript's default behavior of moving declarations to the top. You have an `a` variable in your function scope. This is how it looks like when you're executing it:

```
"use strict"

console.log(a); //undefined 
var a = "a";
function b(){
  var a;
  console.log(a); // Undefined because a is not set
  a = "a1";
  console.log(a); // here is "a1"
}
b();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have another variable a defined in function b, so it' like this:

```
function b() {
  var a;
  console.log(a);
  a = "a1";
  console.log(a);
}
```