# JavaScript Global Variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have already read [Surprised that global variable has undefined value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085839/surprised-that-global-variable-has-undefined-value-in-javascript).

But my problem is differ because I have not created same variable name inside..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var all_ap;
    var url = "http://localhost/example/php-code/json.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        all_ap = result;
        console.log(result);
    });
    console.log(all_ap);
});
```

These are the console results.

```
undefined
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Seems like `console.log(all_ap);` works before `console.log(result);` according to results of above.

Why is that? How should I make `all_ap` variable works?

Comment: It's undefined because you are trying to use it *before* it's been assigned any value.  `$.getJSON` is asynchronous.

Comment: That's not a global variable.

Comment: You must read about asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous function thus callback provided to it gets called after it's finished in the future. That's why your `console.log(all_app)` gets called first because it's called synchronously just after `$.getJSON`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me that how I modify above code to getJSON result to global variable? I read  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call. But It is hard to understand it. Can you please edit your answer how I correct my issuie?